# Time class comparison

Tags: c++

```
bool operator < (Time obj_a, Time obj_b)
{
 return ((obj_a.hours<=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes<=obj_b.minutes) &&  
 (obj_a.hours<=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes<=obj_b.minutes));
}
bool operator > (Time obj_a, Time obj_b)
{
 return (obj_a.hours>=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes>=obj_b.minutes);
}
bool operator == (Time obj_a, Time obj_b)
{
 return (obj_a.hours==obj_b.hours && obj_a.minutes==obj_b.minutes);
}
```

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with these operators.They are comparing time of hours and minutes.but i am not getting correct comparison.I have defined a class of Time in which hours and minutes are stored.

Comment: What are they doing wrong?

Comment: when i compare a time of say 10:30<11:20.it gives false.

Comment: `&&` is wrong and why not `return obj_a.hours*60+obj_a.minutes < obj_b.hours*60+obj_b.minutes`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong with this code. First off, you're reducing `<` comparisons to `<=` comparisons, which (if the rest of your logic were correct) would mean that equal times would compare either `<` or `>`, depending on the order of arguments to the comparison routines.

Then,

```
((obj_a.hours<=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes<=obj_b.minutes) &&  
 (obj_a.hours<=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes<=obj_b.minutes))
```

performs exactly the same comparison twice in an `&&`, so it's actually doing just

```
obj_a.hours<=obj_b.hours || obj_a.minutes<=obj_b.minutes
```

This doesn't work because it wants *either* the hours, *or* the minutes to be `<=`. That means `11:30` <= `10:40` because `30 <= 40`.

The easiest way to tackle this problem is to reduce your comparisons on time objects to comparisons on minutes only, e.g.

```
a.hours * 60 + a.minutes < b.hours * 60 + b.minutes
```

Comment: i am so embarrased right now that why i even asked this question.thanks a lot for helping my dumb brain.